# Python rest api post article, update problem

Tags: categories, rest-api, python

I searched about how to post new article by python.
and it worked. Here is sample of my code

```
res = requests.post(urljoin(WP_URL, "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"),
                    data=json.dumps(payload),
                    headers={'Content-type': "application/json"},
                    auth=(WP_USERNAME, WP_PASSWORD))
```

After running this code, I could find new article was added on my wordpress admin page.

But I found some problem.
Even though that new article has a right category, I was not able to find new article from that category page.
(I will add some images to explain my problem)

1. New article generated! Good! This article's category is "파이썬 에러".
   [image]
2. But when I press 보기(show) button on category "파이썬 에러", there is any new article I can find.
   [image]

But if I press 'edit' button on new article and then just press "update" button immediately not changing anything, I can find that new article on category page.
How to skip this unnecessary step?

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin of any kind?

Comment: I didn't add any plugin about caching.. I guess?..